# TypeError con NoneType en función recursiva para contar elementos de una lista

Tags: python, funciones, recursión, tipos

Tengo un programa para contar los elementos de una lista mediante una función:

```
def lenn(Lista):
    if Lista==[]:
        return 0
    else:
        1+lenn(Lista[1:])
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'

¿De dónde sale el `NoneType`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás implementando mal la recursión:

```
def lenn(Lista):
    if Lista==[]:
        return 0
    else:
        1+lenn(Lista[1:]) # <<<<<<<<<<<
```

En el `else` se llama a la función recursivamente pero no retornas nada explícitamente. En Python todo método o función que termine sin haber ejecutado un estamento `return` explícito retorna `None` por defecto, por lo que la segunda llamada es:

```
else:
    1+None
```

Simplemente usa `return` en esa línea:

```
def lenn(lista: list) -> int:
    if not lista:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1 + lenn(lista[1:]) # Retorna un entero
```

No uses `if Lista==[]` para ver si una lista está vacía, hay varias razones, en Python tanto los contenedores estándar (`list`, `set`, `dict`, etc) como las cadenas vacías se evalúa como `False`.

Hay dos razones principales para no hacerlo:

### **Es ineficiente**

`Lista==[]` fuerza a crear un nuevo objeto `list` vacío (`[]`) e iterar sobre ambos para ver si son iguales, luego el recolector de basura tiene que eliminar el objeto de memoria... Es un gasto de recursos tanto de RAM como de CPU innecesarios, creamos un nuevo objeto solo para ver si otro está vacío o no.

### Las convenciones de estilo

Las propias convenciones de estilo para código Python definidas en [PEP - 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) lo dejan muy claro (traducción propia):

> Para secuencias, (cadenas, listas, tuplas), usa el hecho de que las
>   secuencias vacías son falsas:
>
> ```
> # Correcto:
> if not seq:
> if seq:
>
> # Incorrecto:
> if len(seq):
> if not len(seq):
> ```

La segunda es solo una recomendación/convención, la primera es inapelable.

Comment: Hola, me sí me sirvió, muchaas gracias. Sin embargo, no entiendo por qué es que no debería usar `if Lista==[]` y por qué es mejor usar `if not Lista`. Soy nuevo programando, muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola @Chifrijo, he editado la respuesta intentando argumentar algo mejor el tema, mira al final. Se puede argumentar en favor o en contra,  `if len(lista) == 0:`  podría incluso ser aceptable porque hay objetos fuera del estándar que no se evalúan como falsos si están vacíos (arrays de NumPy por ejemplo), pero `lista == []` en mi opinión no está nunca justificado. Saludos.